# Review my water sensor

Tags: comparator

Please review my water sensor circuit, let me know any problems, suggestions.

I am not sure if it will work.

[image]

Ref:
https://www.homemade-circuits.com/anti-corrosion-probes-for-water-level/

Comment: I think it rather rests on what J3 actually is and where the wire from pin 4 of U3 goes.

Comment: J3 is two simple stainless steel electrodes.  the wire(from pin4) is for another logic ic.

Comment: I would, at least, do a simulation of the behavior of my circuit to see if this is "viable", in any case for the first part of U2A + U2B. Résistive or capacitive sensor ? What will you do sensing ?

Comment: Thanks again.  I will study simulation tools.  Its resistive sensor. referenced from https://makingcircuits.com/blog/anti-corrossive-water-level-probe-circuit/

Comment: I think you will have to experiment with this and make small changes for the best operation. Both on a breadboard, and again on a PCB.  But it looks like it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of simulation with a "capacitive" sensor. Same behavior with "resistor".

Same functional schematic (first left part) made with CMOS device CD4093. Manual switching for simulation.

Trigger points of CD4093 to 3 V (high) and 2V (low).

Your schematic should then "work".

[image]

Added 2 simulations ... Measuring Rx or Cx ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pedro  If you want, I can add a "light modified" circuit with some "measuring" capability.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place a resistor (something large, but not too large) across J1-pin1 and GND. Place a resistor across J1-pin2 and GND (something large, but not too large).
2. The ground coupling between the water and the circuitry will be the major interference comes through.
3. Differential/ratio-metric input configurations can improve reception and noise discrimination.
4. If you are serious enough, modulation / demodulation will very much improve the S/N while increasing the sensitivity.